# Cannot show my citations

Tags: citing

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}


\begin{document}

\section{Background}\label{sec:intro}

Most of the restaurants nowadays are using conventional food-ordering method where the customers place their orders to the waiters and the waitresses directly. This has been time-wasting and paper-wasting \citep*{Bora2012}.The device is connected to the restaurant’s database, all the information of the meals will be shown on the screen. The customers can place the orders by just touch on the screen of the device while the waiters and waitresses can concentrate to serve the customer order. It is believed to be able to improve the restaurant’s services \citep*{Purnama2007}.  

\end{document}
```

[image: The output of the citation]

this is example of my bib file..

```
@article{Bora2012,
author = {Bora, Paresh R and Gupta, Eshan},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Ruby/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley 
Desktop/Downloaded/Bora, Gupta - 2012 - APPLICATION ON ORDER MANAGEMENT SYSTEM IN RESTAURANTS.pdf:pdf},
keywords = {android,tablet,touch technology,wi-fi,wireless food ordering system},
number = {2},
pages = {59--62},
title = {{APPLICATION ON ORDER MANAGEMENT SYSTEM IN RESTAURANTS}},
volume = {1},
year = {2012}
}
```

Why does my output show like this?

Thank for help :)
I have put my file in same folder

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include the actual bibliography in your document.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP had simply forgotten to add `\bibliography{..}`.